# Create a process using redirection arguments using one-liner?

Tags: c#, process

A typical call may look like this:

```
executable.exe argument1 argument2 < inputfile.txt
```

I want to capture the arguments (which is not a problem) but I do not know how to, without error, use the inputfile.txt as standard input. I know that I can manually write to the input stream this file but I would like to be able to use the command "as is" above - which works in the command window.

How can I do this with System.Diagnostics.Process class?